# How to set H1 tag on my site's homepage that has a logo?

Tags: seo, html, heading

Hi so on my website I only have a logo etc, and I don't use any headline/banner (h1) on the homepage.

I wanted to ask how do I place a H1 tag into this homepage which I've read is good for SEO? My other pages do have appropriate h1 tags.

Can anyone please suggest a solution if it's needed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no heading content then placing a `<h1>` there will do you no good and it won't be any worse than it is since you say you have no content there anyway. So leave it out altogether.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot 